# Registration form validation in realtime using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Here's a project from my course on jQuery. It doesn't seem to validate. I get no response in real time and on submission. This project has used jQueryUI. Thanks in advance.

the html:

```
<html>
<head>  
<link type="text/css" href="general.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link type="text/css" href="jqueryui/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" />  
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jqueryui/js/jquery-ui-1.8.15.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="validationtest.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="switcher"></div><p>

<input type="button" id="clickform" value="Register" />

<div id="container">

    <form id="customForm">
        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text" />
                <span id="nameInfo">What's your name?</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" type="text" />
            <span id="emailInfo">Valid E-mail please, you will need it to log in!                    </span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pass1">Password</label>
            <input id="pass1" name="pass1" type="password" />
            <span id="pass1Info">At least 5 characters: letters, numbers and '_'</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="pass2">Confirm Password</label>
            <input id="pass2" name="pass2" type="password" />
            <span id="pass2Info">Confirm password</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <br /><input id="send" name="send" type="button" value="Send" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

The Validation.js script can be found here. [jsfiddle.net/Dwz96/](http://jsfiddle.net/Dwz96/)

Comment: Are you sure the JS files are loaded correctly?

Comment: If you go to the source and click on valifationtest.js does it open up? Do inspect element on chrome or firefox to make sure the file is loaded.

Comment: Yes it does open up. I highly doubt it's getting executed though.

Comment: If memory serves you shouldn't put `$(document).ready(function()` in the javascript file.

Comment: Thanks alot, I replaced $(document) with jQuery(document). It works.